# Applying math to values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var myarray = ["5,35.0", "15,45.0", "25,45.0", "35,50.0", "45,60.0", "55,65.0", "65,60.0", "75,60.0", "85,70.0", "95,80.0"]
```

the values correspond to x,y points on a graph.

I need to apply math to each y value to change the y-axis scale. To keep it simple, let's say I need to multiply each y value by 2.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through every element and split them via ',' and then do the MATH over it and save it back.

Say,

```
for(var i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
    var temp = (parseFloat(myarray[i].split(',')[1])).toFixed(2);
    temp = temp * 2; 
    myarray[i] = myarray[i].split(',')[0] + "," + temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the array, converting the string to a pair of numbers, performing the addition ensuring that the decimal place is kept intact.

```
var out = myarray.map(function (el) {
  var xy = el.split(',').map(Number);
  xy[1] = (xy[1] * 2).toFixed(1);
  return xy.join(',');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/252vg/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly,

```
var myarray = ["5,35.0", "15,45.0", "25,45.0", "35,50.0", "45,60.0", "55,65.0", "65,60.0", "75,60.0", "85,70.0", "95,80.0"];

var y = 0;
var x = 0;

for(var i in myarray) {
    y = parseFloat(myarray[i].split(",")[1]);
    x = parseFloat(myarray[i].split(",")[0]);
    y = y * 2; // or your operation
    myarray[i] = x + "," + y;
}

console.log(myarray);
```

HTH

Comment: no need `x = parseFloat(myarray[i].split(",")[0]);` for this conversion

Comment: Just an enhancement to show to OP that if required s/he can get the `x` value as well for any `Maths` on it.